# Where does zabbix store trapper data?

Tags: zabbix

I'm trying to retreive the results from all trapper items, I assume it is stored in the database under the history table but would like to confirm if maybe it's stored somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't depend on *Type* of item (Zabbix Agent, Zabbix Trapper, ...), but on *Type of information* (Numeric (float), Character, Text, ...). It will be in some history* (history_uint, history_str, ...) table.

But keep in mind, that direct DB access is not good idea. Better concept is the API access - https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/api. Just construct API request and then you don't need to care about DB table name.